# Install of google/apiclient-services failed when I run composer require google/apiclient

Tags: google-calendar-api, laravel-7, google-api-php-client

In Laravel 7.0 Windows environment,
I want to integrate google calendar. When I run `composer require google/apiclient` my installation stucks on `- Downloading google/apiclient-services (v0.224.1)` after long time waiting it shows the following error in the cmd.

```
>    Install of google/apiclient-services failed
>  - Installing google/apiclient (v2.12.1): Extracting archive
    0 [>---------------------------]
Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
The following exception is caused by a process timeout
Check https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#process-timeout for details


 > [Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessTimedOutException]
  The process "git clone --no-checkout -- "https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client-services.git" "C:\User
  s\amu\Desktop\projects\laravel google calendar integration\blog\vendor\google\apiclient-services" && cd /D "C:\User
  s\amu\Desktop\projects\laravel google calendar integration\blog\vendor\google\apiclient-services" && git remote add
   composer -- "https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client-services.git" && git fetch composer && git remote
   set-url origin -- "https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client-services.git" && git remote set-url compose
  r -- "https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client-services.git"" exceeded the timeout of 300 seconds.


>require [--dev] [--dry-run] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--prefer-install PREFER-INSTALL] [--fixed] [--no-suggest] [--no-progress] [--no-update] [--no-install] [--no-scripts] [--update-no-dev] [-w|--update-with-dependencies] [-W|--update-with-all-dependencies] [--with-dependencies] [--with-all-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--apcu-autoloader-prefix APCU-AUTOLOADER-PREFIX] [--] [<packages>]...
```

It seems `google/apiclient-services` cannot be installed. does anyone know what should I do?